# The second argument to copy() function cannot be a directory and move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move

Tags: php

in the code

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){


 $post_image=$_FILES['post_image']['name'];
 $post_image_tmp=$_FILES['post_image']['tmp_name'];

    if($post_image='' ){
        echo "<script> alert ('please fill in all fields')</script>";
        exit();

    }
else{

move_uploaded_file($post_image_tmp,"news_images/$post_image");
?>
```

I get this error

> Warning: move_uploaded_file(): The second argument to copy() function
>   cannot be a directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\MyCMS\admin\insert_post.php
>   on line 107
>
> Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move
>   'C:\xampp\tmp\php946C.tmp' to 'news_images/' in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\MyCMS\admin\insert_post.php on line 107

Please help I'am just newbie.

Comment: evasd, please put all the relevant code, where is the move_uploaded_file code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

= is assignment operator. 
use comparison operator == here.

```
if($post_image == '' ) {
```